# Proper way to communicate between fragments and replacing a fragment with new one in a single activity app

Tags: android, android-fragments

Suppose, we have a single activity app. The layout contains a single FrameLayout. The activity has a method called replaceFragment that takes a fragment and replaces a fragment if any in the FrameLayout, like this:

The method in the activity:

```
replaceFragment(Fragment fragment)
{
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment).commit;
}
```

Then from any fragment we can call this method to replace itself with a new fragment, and also pass data to that new fragment like this:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).replaceFragment(AnotherFragment.newInstance("data", "data"));
```

What I wanna know is, I have seen alot of people say that Single activity app is good, but it's complicated to make. But, from what I can see this seems easy. Am I missing something, is something wrong with this kind of architecture that I am not aware of? Obviously this is just an example we would need some more methods.

Answer (score 1):

Single activity app has its own pros and cons and I think the main disadvantage is complexity especially when the app is large and complex.

For example, one frameLayout and managing fragments would be a lot difficult when you have different kinds of screens like bottomNavigtaionBar, drawerLayout, one custom actionBar for home screen and another for others, fullscreens like login, register or welcome screens.

But in technical world, nothing is impossible if there are enough time, resource and skill. Although you can do all those things manually by yourself, I would prefer to use some libraries as now is 2020 and a lot of libraries have already become stable.

I like to recommend [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate) from jack pack for fragment management because it is officially supported by google and it is really powerful, supported by android studio and have only some minor weaknesses. For communication between fragments, I would recommend [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) and [viewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) as these two really work well with single activity app and would make the development a lot easier.